# Mist main wallet address changed after instalation

Tags: ether, mist, addresses, installation

During the instalation of mist on a mac I get to the following screen:

[image]

I then have to wait for synching to complete. During this time I can deposit ether into my wallet using Bitcoin or just use the address displayed and make a straight transfer from another ether wallet to this one. I copied the address down and then just waited for the synching to complete.

The next morning I found that mist had closed on my laptop so I opened it back up and discovered that the main account address had changed.

[image]

I checked the keystore folder and there was only one keystore saved there with an address that matched the one in mist.

What happen to the other address. I searched for it on my laptop and it is only in the text file I copied it to. If I had sent ether to this now missing address, I would have been screwed. This has got me spooked. Why did the address change ? My next step is to scan for malware. And yes, I did check the SHA256 hash against the downloaded mist application file before I installed it.

Any help will be appreciated. I am NOT going to use this wallet until I have an answer.

Thanks,

Warren

These images are not screenshots of my wallet

Comment: Could your issue be related to these ones? https://github.com/kvhnuke/etherwallet/issues/1528 https://github.com/kvhnuke/etherwallet/issues/1539 https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/915